AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'
I'm trying to run a test suite on FastAPI endpoints that use a database connection. I'm using FastAPI's dependency injection on the endpoint, which I attempt to override with a test database during testing.
# app/dependencies.py

from typing import Annotated, AsyncGenerator 

from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from fastapi import Depends

from app.settings import settings


async def get_db() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    db_config = ConnectionConfig(
        service="mysql",
        driver="asyncmy",
        user=settings.MYSQL_USER,
        password=settings.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        host=settings.MYSQL_HOST,
        database=settings.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    )
    engine = create_async_engine(
            get_db_url(config=db_config), echo=settings.DEVELOPMENT
        )
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        yield session


# test_db.py

from typing import AsyncGenerator, Iterator
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

import pytest
from fastapi import status
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from sqlmodel import SQLModel
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

from app.dependencies import get_db
    

@pytest.fixture
async def session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    engine = create_async_engine("sqlite+aiosqlite://")
    async with engine.connect() as cxn, cxn.begin() as txn:
        await cxn.run_sync(SQLModel.metadata.create_all)
        async_session = AsyncSession(
            bind=cxn, join_transaction_mode="create_savepoint"
        )
        yield async_session

        await txn.rollback()
    await engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture  
def client(session: AsyncSession):  
    def get_session_override():  
        return session

    app = create_app()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = get_session_override  

    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c  

    app.dependency_overrides.clear()  


@pytest.mark.anyio
def test_create_attestation(
    attestations: Iterator[Attestation], client: TestClient
):  
    for attestation in attestations:
        payload = {"topic": "some topic"}
        resp = client.post(url="/v1/upload", json=payload)
        assert resp.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK


# app/routers.py

@router.post(
    path="/upload",
)
async def upload(
    req: UploadRequest, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)
):
    row = Row(**req.model_dump())
    db.add(row)
    await db.commit()

When running the endpoints directly, the dependency injection works, but in the test suite, I get the following error:
CRITICAL root:app.py:51 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 105, in receive
    return self.receive_nowait()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 100, in receive_nowait
    raise WouldBlock
anyio.WouldBlock

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 118, in receive
    return receiver.item
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MemoryObjectItemReceiver' object has no attribute 'item'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 159, in call_next
    message = await recv_stream.receive()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 120, in receive
    raise EndOfStream
anyio.EndOfStream

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/arthur/app.py", line 49, in middleware
    response = await call_next(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 165, in call_next
    raise app_exc
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 151, in coro
    await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 85, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 278, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/hoangsx/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-AbbVieInc(O365)/workspace/projects/arthur-api/arthur/routes.py", line 95, in create_attestation_topic
    db.add(row)
    ^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'add'

I've tried to modify the fixture scopes, as well as trying to iterate through the async_generator using __anext__, but I'm still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

I noticed that session is an async fixture. Are you using pytest-asyncio? Otherwise, that might be why it's not working.

That was the fix!
